# kohana framework doesn't load module on linux server while load it perfectly on mamp

Tags: php, linux, frameworks, kohana, mamp

well, question is in subject, here i can give you some details. Error is Class QIWI is not found. In bootstrap it is uncommented, when i use

```
    Debug(Kohana::modules())
```

it shown like module is loaded. folder three is

```
    --modules
    --|-qiwi
    ----|--classes
    -------|--Kohana
    ----------|--Qiwi.php (class Kohana_Qiwi)
    -------|Qiwi.php (class Qiwi extends Kohana_Qiwi)
```

i think that is a filename issue, but it seems like files r named correctly

Comment: What version of Kohana are you using?

Comment: Linux filesystems are case sensitive. You ask for class `QIWI` (all capital) while the file is named `Qiwi`, Kohana will go look for a file named `QIWI`. Either rename the file(s) to `QIWI` or use `Qiwi` as a classname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to uncomment this line in bootstrap:

```
spl_autoload_register(array('Kohana', 'auto_load_lowercase'));
```